# how can I update two fields with a single date picker in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

In my `javascript` code I'm using datepicker, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function datepicker(element) {
        element.datepicker({
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImage: "calendar",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
    }
```

and later I'm attaching it to the input with id="startDate":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        datepicker($("#startDate"));
    });
```

it works correctly and fills the startDate input with selected date.
But I also have the second input, called endDate - is there a way to handle it within datepicker, so that when user selects startDate, the endDate is populated automatically with a selected date incremented of 2 days?

Comment: Can you add a [mre]?

Comment: Check this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55804024/automatically-changes-end-date-after-start-date-is-picked

Comment: Which date picker library and what version?

Comment: It looks like you are using the jQuery UI datepicker ([`buttonImage` is an option](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-buttonImage) for that), but you are [initialising it incorrectly](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).  If you *are* using that datepicker, a basic search like "*jquery ui datepicker set end date*" turns up many answers here already, here's a random example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721133/jquery-datepickers-setting-end-date-from-a-start-date

Answer (score 0):

Try having same class for two inputs and pass the class name instead of id and pass it to `datepicker($(".dateField"));`